# refresh page with post request -> csrf failed

Tags: django, csrf

I try do login in site

```
@csrf_protect
def home(request):

    if request.POST :
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)

    return render(request,'base.html',{})
```

and when i submit form, it's ok - user is login, but if I refresh this page after this - csrf fail.
What my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should suppose to redirect after logging in:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

#...
if user:
    if user.is_active:
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('home')
#...
```

where `home` is the url name, see [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) docs for more details of how to use it.